# Change.org Script, Tracking data 20% of the time and not all the time

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
window.shouldTrackLoadEvents = Math.random() < 0.2;
window.trackVanillaEvent = function(label, additionalProperties) {
    if (!window.shouldTrackLoadEvents) return;
    var trackRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = {
      user_uuid: '463a5c10-000f-11e9-a12f-d788c2d9c1de',
      locale: 'en-GB',
      mobile: false,
      country_code: '' || 'NG',
      id: 'user_',
      path: window.location.pathname,
      browser: 'Chrome',
      platform: 'Microsoft Windows',
      user_agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
    };
    if (additionalProperties && typeof additionalProperties === 'object') {
      for (key in additionalProperties) {
        if (additionalProperties.hasOwnProperty(key)) data[key] = additionalProperties[key];
      }
    }
    trackRequest.open('POST', '/api-proxy/-/event_tracker');
    trackRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    trackRequest.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '073753e85ee029f23ffcd51cbdeca7a3');
    trackRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ label: label, data: data, }));
  }
```

Found the script at the `head tag` of `change.org` source code.

What I don't really understand here is why a `random number` is compared with 0.2
before some data-tracking decision is made

Based on my understanding of this algorithm;

I understand that some data are asynchronously sent to to /api-proxy/-/event_tracker

and I understand that `Math.random() < 0.2` implies that the data should be sent 20% of the time.

But what I don't understand is that, if they have to send some data or track some data for whatever reasons why are they doing this 20% of the time and not all the time?

Comment: Depending on what studies they're doing with that data, 20% might give them a large-enough sample size. They can save resources (CPU, network, etc.) by not dealing with the rest of the requests.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks a bunch for your comment. I was startled when I came across the code and couldn't help but throw it in the community